# Microservice Architecture Diagram

Tags: architecture, microservices

I am developing micro-services architecture using Spring Boot.

My architecture has around 10 Service each running with 2 instances each behind HAProxy(Load-balancer)

Also there are applications running like Jenkins, Grafana etc.

Now I want an interface where I can view all nodes which are working as green, not working as red, show dependency b/w nodes. I mean I want to view the complete architecture so that any one can understand the architecture. How should I do it?

Comment: Hystrix dashboard can show you the state of every microservice

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Grafana, you can try this panel:

https://grafana.com/plugins/jdbranham-diagram-panel

You can define a graph of your architecture, and assign metrics to the nodes based on which you can color them red / green.

You would need some metrics about the health of the nodes. You can use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) for example to collect some standard Java indicators like memory and cpu usage of the JVM. Or you can publish custom indicators if you want.